# Export / download file from Google Drive using C# produces an empty, zero-byte file

Tags: c#, api, download, export, cloud

I'm attempting to download a file from Google Drive using C# & Google.Apis.Drive.v3 and I'm getting an empty, zero-byte file (see code below). I'm uploading files OK, but can't get the download to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`code`

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
static string ApplicationName = "Test001";
private DriveService _service = null;
public async Task downloadFile(string url, string lstrDownloadFile)
{

    // Authorize API access
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
        // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
        string credPath = "token.json";
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Debug.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Drive API service.
    _service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

    // Attempt download
    // Iterate through file-list and find the relevant file
    FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = _service.Files.List();
    listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, originalFilename, size)";
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File lobjGoogleFile = null;
    foreach (var item in listRequest.Execute().Files)
    {
        if (url.IndexOf(string.Format("id={0}", item.Id)) > -1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.OriginalFilename, item.MimeType));
            lobjGoogleFile = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    FilesResource.ExportRequest request = _service.Files.Export(lobjGoogleFile.Id, lobjGoogleFile.MimeType);
    Debug.WriteLine(request.MimeType);
    MemoryStream lobjMS = new MemoryStream();
    await request.DownloadAsync(lobjMS);

    // At this point the MemoryStream has a length of zero?

    lobjMS.Position = 0;
    var lobjFS = new System.IO.FileStream(lstrDownloadFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
    await lobjMS.CopyToAsync(lobjFS);
}
```

Comment: Should've added that lobjGoogleFile.Size = 34596, so it's not a zero-byte file that I'm trying to download.

Comment: I have the same problem, BUT if I set the MimeType to "text/html" it works perfectly (the file content is ok etc). But if I try to set "application/pdf" instead, it downloads a file that is not recognized as a working pdf: "Encountered a sharing violation while accessing path/to/file.pdf" (opened using Foxit Reader).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it's something as simple as not having enabled the Drive API on your project.

I recommend you add the following code. There's likely a download error which is preventing the stream from being filled.

```
FilesResource.ExportRequest request = ...
request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += progress =>
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + progress.Exception?.Message);
            break;
        }
        // other status case statements if you need them
    }
};

MemoryStream lobjMS = ...
```

Then you can drop a breakpoint into the Failed case or look at the exception in the console.